# Does partitioning help with lookups and inserts/updates by primary key?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, partitioning, database-internals

I'm using MariaDB 10.1 and the default InnoDB storage storage, and I have a few tables with currently 10 to 100 million rows. These tables will keep growing a few  million per month, and it's mostly caching.

They either have a single-column primary key (`BIGINT`) or a composite primary key (two `BIGINT` columns) and no AUTO_INCREMENT, and I always insert, select or update by primary key. I also do a lot of joins by primary key, or selects `WHERE PK IN (1, 2, 3, 4...)`.

Also, these tables receive lots of updates per hour, and I usually update them in batches of 5000 or 10000 at a time. We have more inserts and updates than selects for some of these tables.

I have 3 questions:

1. It seems to me that simple selects by PK returning 1 row (`SELECT x, y FROM table WHERE pk = 123`) will have no actual difference in performance with partitioning. Is that right?
2. What about joins or selects as `WHERE PK IN(SELECT PK FROM ...)`? Will it cause more scans to join a partitioned table than a single table?
3. Considering I usually do a lot of concurrent batches (multiple servers may send data at the same time) using:

   - `INSERT INTO X VALUES (1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` or
   - `REPLACE INTO X VALUES(1, 'A'),  (2, 'B'),...`

Will partitioning help with concurrent inserts and updates, say by being able to affect multiple partitions at the same time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: partitioning use cases explained here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/partition-maintenance/ it seems Use case #3 -- hot spot, relates to your requirements.

Comment: But if my access is random in the entire table, what's the difference between having a single partition and not being able to fit a single huge index in ram and having lots of smaller indexes but not being able to fit all of them in ram? Wouldn't this end up being the same?

Comment: How do you want to partition this table? By the PK in ranges? This will not improve performance for random acces.

Comment: I'd partition by hash.

Comment: Partitioning is really good for a case like when you have a time series and are querying recent records more often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your questions**

Q1:  If PK is the *Partition key*, a "point query" (`WHERE PK = constant`) on the Partition key will do "pruning", then (hopefully) use an index in the single partition it found.  No improvement over having a simple table with a suitable index.
Q1:  If PK is the `PRIMARY KEY`, but *not* the Partition key, then the query must open and look in every partition to find the row, hence slower.

Q2:  Generally `IN ( SELECT ... )` performs poorly, *very* poorly in some cases, and should be avoided.  Use a `JOIN` instead.  For partitioning, "pruning" will probably not be used.  Hence slow.

Q3:  `INSERT` may be about the same speed, regardless.  A plain table *may* be faster due to less complexity.
Q3:  `REPLACE` is `DELETE` + `INSERT`.  `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` is *usually* a better construct; see if it applies.  But, again, no performance improvement.

**IN**

`WHERE PK IN (1, 2, 3, 4...)` -- I think I heard that if the list is 'short', it will use partition pruning.  Or skip the pruning if the list is long.  In either case, a simple table with an index on PK will be at least as fast.

**Pruning**

Think of pruning this way:  First it must find the partition (which acts very much like a "sub table"), then it must use an index (if available) to drill down to the desired row(s).  Without partitioning, it skips the pruning step; but the BTree index is *slightly* deeper.  So it is a trade-off.

Note:  This often means that the optimal set of indexes for a partitioned table and the equivalent non-partitioned table are different.

**Case 3**

The caveat "A table's index is too big to be cached, but the index for one partition is cacheable" does not seem to apply to your situation.  Case 3 came from a time-series wherein most of the activity was in the latest partition (and `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))`) and that partition fit in the buffer_pool but the entire table did not.

(That is, I agree with Natan, not Jarwad, about the relevance of Case 3.)

**BY HASH**

`BY HASH` -- not useful.  (From the link:  "PARTITION BY RANGE is the only useful method.")  (Or at least, I have yet to see a use case of Hash where performance benefits.)

**Ingestion**

"growing a few million per *month*" That's not very fast.  "growing a few million per *day*" would begin to be challenging, at which point I would point you at my [*high speed ingestion blog*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-high-speed-ingestion/) .  Even so, you might take one tip from there -- Load the changes into a transient table, then do the insert/replace/iodku/update/etc from it to the 'real' table.